# error building docker image: Error: dependency ‘cmdstanr’ is not available

Tags: r, linux, docker, stan

I have a problem building a docker image with the following codes:

```
FROM rocker/verse:latest
MAINTAINER xxx

RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils ed libnlopt-dev libgdal-dev libudunits2-dev cargo jags libcairo2-dev libxt-dev libgeos-dev \
&& apt-get clean \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/

# Install rstan
RUN install2.r --error --deps TRUE \
rstan \
&& rm -rf /tmp/downloaded_packages/ /tmp/*.rds

# Global site-wide config -- neeeded for building packages
RUN mkdir -p $HOME/.R/ \
&& echo "CXXFLAGS=-O3 -mtune=native -march=native -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-function -flto -ffat-lto-objects  -Wno-unused-local-typedefs \n" >> $HOME/.R/Makevars

# Config for rstudio user
RUN mkdir -p $HOME/.R/ \
&& echo "CXXFLAGS=-O3 -mtune=native -march=native -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-function -flto -ffat-lto-objects  -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-ignored-attributes -Wno-deprecated-declarations\n" >> $HOME/.R/Makevars \
&& echo "rstan::rstan_options(auto_write = TRUE)\n" >> /home/rstudio/.Rprofile \
&& echo "options(mc.cores = parallel::detectCores())\n" >> /home/rstudio/.Rprofile


RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('cmdstanr', repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org', dependencies=TRUE)"

# Install rstan
RUN install2.r --error --deps TRUE \
rstan \
loo \
bayesplot \
rstanarm \
rstantools \
shinystan \
ggmcmc \
tidybayes \
LaplacesDemon \
&& rm -rf /tmp/downloaded_packages/ /tmp/*.rds

RUN install2.r --error --deps TRUE \
zoo  \
mgcv \
lubridate \
stringr  \
loo \
jsonlite \
scales \
directlabels \
betareg \
extrafont \
pointdensityP \
&& rm -rf /tmp/downloaded_packages/ /tmp/*.rds

# Install Roboto condensed
RUN wget -O /tmp/rc.zip https://fonts.google.com/download?family=Roboto%20Condensed \
&& cd /usr/share/fonts \
&& sudo mkdir googlefonts \
&& cd googlefonts \
&& sudo unzip -d . /tmp/rc.zip \
&& sudo chmod -R --reference=/usr/share/fonts/truetype /usr/share/fonts/googlefonts \
&& sudo fc-cache -fv \
&& rm -rf /tmp/rc.zip \
&& Rscript --slave --no-save --no-restore-history -e "extrafont::font_import(prompt=FALSE)"
```

And I failed to build the docker image with the following error:

> #10 224.1 Error: dependency ‘cmdstanr’ is not available------executor failed running [/bin/sh -c install2.r --error --deps TRUE rstan loo bayesplot rstanarm rstantools shinystan ggmcmc tidybayes LaplacesDemon && rm -rf /tmp/downloaded_packages/ /tmp/*.rds]: exit code: 1

Can anyone help me with the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The [Getting Started with CmdStanR](https://mc-stan.org/cmdstanr/articles/cmdstanr.html) vignette says you should use

```r
install.packages("cmdstanr", 
   repos = c("https://mc-stan.org/r-packages/", getOption("repos")))
```

you're trying to install it from a CRAN mirror, which won't work because the package isn't on CRAN. (I haven't tested, you might want to install `cmdstanr` *after* you install Stan ...